# NodeJS Prevent rest of function from running

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm having some problems with the following route:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.user) res.redirect("/");

    Survey.find({ surveyName: req.body.surveyName }, function(error, survey) {
        if(survey) { 
            res.redirect('back');
            res.end();
        }
    });

    // save the survey code here
});
```

Want I'm trying to do is reassure that the client goes back to the previous page if a survey with that name already exists; however, the check runs the code (regardless whether it exists or not) and continues on with trying to save the survey. Any insight how to fix this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do this:

```
Survey.find({ surveyName: req.body.surveyName }, function(error, survey) {
    if(survey) { 
        res.redirect('back');
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    // save the survey code here
});
```

EDIT: mind that async nature of javascript